# Click on an element to let the elements after it slide forward

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm practicing and trying to make an instagram page.

Now the layout is all done but i have some problems with javascript.

How do i make the effect like instagram as the gif below?

[image]

I make the css display: none, when the element is clicked.

But i'm not sure how to make the elements after it slide forward.

Please refer to the gif below.

[image]

I idea was:

When an element is clicked, wrap the elements after it, and then change the wrap css position.
I used jquery wrap(), but it didn't work as i wanted.

for example, the original code is like this

```
<div class="box">111</div>
<div class="box">222</div>
<div class="box">333</div>
<div class="box">444</div>
<div class="box">555</div>
```

I used

```
      $(".box").click(function () {
        $(this).nextAll().wrap('<div class="wrap"></div>');
      });
```

if i click 222, the result would be

```
<div class="box">111</div>
<div class="box">222</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">333</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">444</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">555</div>
</div>
```

but i want it to be like this

```
<div class="box">111</div>
<div class="box">222</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">333</div>
    <div class="box">444</div>
    <div class="box">555</div>
</div>
```

How do i wrap all these element together, instead of giving a wrap to each?

Or is there any better way to make this effect?

Comment: Have you looked at [wrapAll()](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) method ?

Comment: That's the method i'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind that once you wrap them, the `nextAll()` will not work exactly the same. But that's all about the learning to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that a part of your question has already been answered by @charlietfl, so this here is just about the animation. This here is just one way to do it and there are a lot of others to do so.

An example code is available below.

So how does it work?

Apply a wrapper to the box to get a simple element to animate (yes you could also just animate the box with margin and without the wrapper. The wrapper is just for making an easy padding animation.)

If the .close span is clicked, the wrapper is set to the following CSS:

```
width: 0;
opacity: 0;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
```

Because the wrapper has

```
transition: 0.5s;
```

it will slide nicely to the left. (transition applies to width, opacity and padding in this case)

And maybe think about doing something with the z-index (opacity animation is a bit ugly in the front of other elements).

I hope i could help anyone - Have a nice day!

```js
$(".close").click(function(){
    var el = $(this).closest(".box_wrapper");
    el.css("width", 0);
    el.css("opacity", 0);
    el.css("padding-left", 0);
    el.css("padding-right", 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.remove();
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.box_wrapper {
  float: left;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.box {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
} 

.close {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box_wrapper">
  <div class="box"><span class="close">X</span>1</div>
</div>
<div class="box_wrapper">
  <div class="box"><span class="close">X</span>2</div>
</div>
<div class="box_wrapper">
  <div class="box"><span class="close">X</span>3</div>
</div>
<div class="box_wrapper">
  <div class="box"><span class="close">X</span>4</div>
</div>
```

And yes, this code is not perfect. There are some things to improve like the padding on .box_wrapper & .box, the opacity animation and the js. (can be simplified by a lot)